# Save the time that the radio question was selected

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, radio-button, react-typescript

I want to save the time that my user saved his/her answer for a radio button type question.
Is that possible in HTML? can I implement it with some other coding language or package? If it matters I'm writing in react.js typescript. For example here are some questions and I want to save each time the user selects his/her answer:

```
<label htmlFor="screenhours"> <b> 4. How many hours a day on average do you use a computers? </b> {" "} </label>
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="screenhours" value="1" required onChange={onChange(4)} />{" "}
    Less than an hour &emsp;  <br />
    <input type="radio" name="screenhours" value="2" onChange={onChange(4)} />
    {" "}
    Between 1-3 hours &emsp;  
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="screenhours" value="3" onChange={onChange(4)} />
    {" "}
    Between 3-5 hours &emsp;
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="screenhours" value="4" onChange={onChange(4)} />{" "}
    More than 5 hours &emsp;  <br />
</p>
```

Comment: you can get the value attribute of the radio input elem and save where you want. Alternative if you're managing state in form of object, you can set the object property through HTML elem name attribute.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want to hear but it's certainly possible to get the current time in the change call back. Since you're using React it doesn't make sense to ask how to do it in HTML since you are not writing HTML directly

Answer (score 0):

If you're using functional components, here's how you can get the value of radio input element.

```
export const Sample = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        screenhours: 0
    })

    const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const { name, value, checked, valueAsNumber } = e.target

        // name: must be state object property
        // value: that you set for radio input element
        // valueAsNumber: if you want to get integer value

        setState({ ...state, [name]: value })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <label htmlFor="screenhours">
                {' '}
                <b> 4. How many hours a day on average do you use a computers? </b>{' '}
            </label>
            <p>
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="screenhours"
                    value="1"
                    required
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />{' '}
                Less than an hour &emsp; <br />
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="screenhours"
                    value="2"
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />{' '}
                Between 1-3 hours &emsp; <br />
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="screenhours"
                    value="3"
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />{' '}
                Between 3-5 hours &emsp; <br />
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="screenhours"
                    value="4"
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                />{' '}
                More than 5 hours &emsp; <br />
            </p>
        </div>
    )
}
```